# large xml created from oracle has error

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, oracle11g

We have a query that generates an xml file.  The xml is then taken through a javascript routine that is then mapped to the browser using bing maps.   I've edited the query to generate data for another user group and suddenly there is an error in the xml.  Can't figure out what is wrong, the error is "invalid character" deep down in the document. Here are the things I've tried

- checked the information in the db to ensure there aren't any special characters, there arent.
- tried to force load the latest xml, similar to [this example](http://snipplr.com/view/45873/).
- ran another xml through the javascript routine, it works, ran second xml, doesn't.
- the error is "invalid character" when viewed with IE, open with notepad++ cant see anything that could potentially cause problems

This is the oracle query used to generate the xml, the only part that changed was the contents of 'description', from `sitedesc` to `sitecode`

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("rss", 
            XMLATTRIBUTES('http://www.georss.org/georss' AS "xmlns:georss"),
                    XMLELEMENT("channel",
                                 XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("item",
                                                   XMLFOREST(title AS "title",
                                                              description AS "description",
                                                              point AS "georss:point"))))).EXTRACT('/*')
    FROM (SELECT trim(s.sitedesc) AS title, 
          s.sitecode AS description,
          trim(s.latitude) || ' ' || trim(s.longitude) AS point
          FROM ls s
          WHERE s.sold <> 1
            AND s.longitude != ' '
        )
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its was my file properties, they were not set properly.